# iterate a string based on another string

Tags: python, string

I need to iterate variable Y, compare each iteration with variable 
sublist Variable X  and create a new string with results.

```
Y = 'ABCEF'

X =[('A', 1),('B', 4),('C', 6),('D', 7),('E', 8),('F', 9),('G', 10),('H', 11),('I', 12),('J', 13),('K', 14),('L', 15),('M', 16)]
```

The result is below after iterating Y.

```
Z = '14689'
```

Can someone shade some light on the resolution of this.

```
Y = 'ABCEF'

X =[('A', 1),('B', 4),('C', 6),('D', 7),('E', 8),('F', 9),('G', 10),('H', 11),('I', 12),('J', 13),('K', 14),('L', 15),('M', 16)]
j <= len(X) - 1 
result = ''

for i in Y:
    if i in X[0][j]:
        result.append(X[j])
else: 
    j = j -1
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I am using Python 3

Comment: Is `X` stored as a string (a la JSON) or is that a literal Python list?

Comment: X is a list that contains within list of two digits each

Comment: So why is your question "iterate a string based on another string" when there's only 1 string?

Comment: yes sorry that was a mistake. Title should have been 'Iterate a string based on a list in Python'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
y = 'ABCEF'
x =  [('A', 1),('B', 4),('C', 6),('D', 7),('E', 8),('F', 9),('G', 10),('H', 11),('I', 12),('J', 13),('K', 14),('L', 15),('M', 16)]
result = ''
for i in y: 
    for j in range(len(x)): 
        if i in x[j]:
            result += str(x[j][1])
            break
print(result)
```

the output will be `14689`

Comment: Thank you Habib. Your solution is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

You can creating a mapping dict from `X` so that you can iterate through `Y` to map each character to its value before joining them into a new string:

```
mapping = dict(X)
Z = ''.join(str(mapping[c]) for c in Y)
```

`Z` becomes: `'14689'`